# Debugging an IP in Vivado

Tags: image-processing

I have a custom-made image processing IP in a Vivado FPGA project which does not work properly. The VHDL logic is OK, I have simulated it outside the IP. The fault must be with the AXI interface and how I've connected it to the VHDL module. How can I debug the interface? With ILA? Where should I connect the probes? It's difficult because the signals that I should follow / debug are inside the IP! They aren't visible outside.